# Handle virtual keyboard popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a web app with js, jquery, bootstrap. I have an input field on the bottom of my page. When the android keyboard pops up, I can't see the input field where I'm typing any more. I have read a lot of solutions but all solutions use the fact, that the window size changes when the keyboard pops up. But that's not working.

```
alert($(window).height());

$('input').focus(
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert($(window).height());        
  }, 3000)
)
```

Both alerts show me the same pixel size. I want my page scroll up and down when keyboard opens and closes. But how can I achieve this without knowing when keyboard closes?

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px;">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: does window.innerHeight differ?

Comment: No, window.innerheight doesn't differ

Comment: please share html also

Comment: I wasn't working the last days and now everything is fine. When keyboard opens, the bottom elemts go up, it means the the browser now detects the keyboard. Seems that something changed in the android keyboard or so...Is this problem known to anybody?